# WKWebView ignores onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, wkwebview

Currently I have a WebView which I render using WKWebView and Swift. I have added all the delegates but none of them is getting called. Am I handling it incorrectly ? I did add WKScriptMessageHandler too but none of them is triggering the onlick javascript call.

My swift code is below:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("here - \(message)");
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    print("here - \(message)");
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: (String?) -> Void) {
    print("here - \(prompt)");

}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction ) -> Void in
        completionHandler(false);
    }));
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction ) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: (frame.request.URL?.host)!)!);
        completionHandler(true);
    }));
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);


}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction    navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {}
```

And javascript code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="open_agree();" title="Agree " tabindex="0">Agree </a>
```

**UPDATED: The following code worked for me....**

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having same issue...

Comment: this method worked for me...
func webView(webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?
If this answer works for you please approve it....

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but you should post your update as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Where did you put the createwebviewwithconfiguration?

Comment: It's not working for me..